# Transpose dataset in SAS

Tags: sas, transpose

I want to transpose a simple dataset as left, to become a dataset at the right. They are all numeric variables. Please also make the variable names as I put there (I have a lot of variables I want to follow this pattern), would prefer not to rename them by hand one by one if possible. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Transposing data values into column names can lead to more complicated coding later -- you might end up doing a lot of array processing when simpler `by` `class` and `where` processing of the original structure is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple approach. I added another id for demonstration. You can re-arrange the columns if you like.

```
data have;
input id Vistime v1 v2;
datalines;
1 1 2 5
1 2 3 6
1 3 4 7
2 1 2 5
2 2 3 6
2 3 4 7
;

proc transpose data=have out=temp;
   by id Vistime;
   var v1 v2;
run;

proc transpose data=temp delim=_ out=want(drop=_:);
   by id;
   var col1;
   id _name_ Vistime;
run;
```

Result

```
id v1_1 v2_1 v1_2 v2_2 v1_3 v2_3 
1  2    5    3    6    4    7 
2  2    5    3    6    4    7
```

Comment: Thank you so much!